# Drawing a circle with a line down its center and text on either side in tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

I want to create a circle node with a line completely down the center with text on either side of the line. So far the code below draws a bar the same height as the text, but does not extend through the entire center of the circle. How can I accomplish this?

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (y) [shape=circle,draw] at (0,0) {$\Sigma | f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

There is in tikz the notion of multipart nodes and a shape, circle split, that allows to have a dual part in a circle shape. The problem is that only a horizontal splitting is allowed and doing a vertical splitting requires 1/ to rotate the shape to have a vertical split and 2/ to rotate the inner text in the opposite direction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle split,draw,rotate=90] (y) {\rotatebox{-90}{$\sigma$}
     \nodepart{lower} \rotatebox{-90}{$f$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But doing that with with regular tikz command is very easy and allows a better control on node appearance, and text alignment.

I suggest, to first put your text nodes. Then determine the optimal circle size with the fit library. And last to draw the vertical line.

Here is the corresponding code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=east,baseline] (sigma) at (0,0) {$\sigma$} ;
\node[anchor=west,baseline] (f) at (0,0) {$f$} ;
\node[circle,draw,fit={(sigma)(f)}] (y) {} ;
\draw (y.south) -- (y.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can modify the space between the text and the circle with a `inner sep` parameter on the node y.

If you need several circles with the same diameter, replace the `fit=` with a `minimum width=1cm` (or whatever).

Last, if you need to have closer nodes, add `inner sep=0.5pt` (or any other value) to the first two nodes.

Here is the result with different parameters.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=east,baseline,inner sep=0.5pt] (sigma) at (0,0) {$\sigma$} ;
\node[anchor=west,baseline,inner sep=0.5pt] (f) at (0,0) {$f$} ;
\node[circle,draw,fit={(sigma)(f)},inner sep=1pt] (y) {} ;
\draw (y.south) -- (y.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solutions! I prefer your solution using the fit library, however I don't understand the anchor parts. The sigma has an anchor=east but intuitively it seems like it should be west since it's on the "left" side of the circle. And what does the "baseline" keyword mean? Do you have a link to a page that can explain those parameters in more depth? I've tried finding documentation for the tikz libraries and am having a difficult time finding them.

Comment: The text must be at the center of the the circle. \sigma is at the left, so I want its right extremity to be at this center, hence the `anchor=east. This could have been replaced by a positioning directive `left` (or better `left base`). Concerning baseline, by default tikz aligns the center of nodes. So if you have the two parts with different extension with respect of the text baseline, say 'j' and 't', 'j' would be slightly raised and 't' lowered to respect alignment. With the baseline parameter, it is not the center, but the baseline that is aligned.

Comment: I do not know any specific site, but the tikz doc is very complete and contains these explanations. See for instance the 'positioning nodes'  section, pp. 234